# How to get color to appear the same in Linux everywhere?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, emacs, colors

The screenshot below shows the same Python file opened in emacs on my Ubuntu desktop (left window) and on a computer cluster at work (right window).  The desktop's colour is the default in Ubuntu.  How do I get the cluster's colour to be like the desktop's? My eyes hurt looking at the colours on the right.  I have tried tweaking the profile settings of the Terminal in Ubuntu, as well as inserting `export TERM=xterm-256color` into the cluster's .bash_profile; the colour just doesn't change.

The desktop:

```
uname -a
Linux rcec 4.4.0-92-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 10 09:04:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The work cluster:

```
uname -a
Linux chialn00 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[image]

Comment: More likely a matter of emacs configuration than of plain terminal colors.

Comment: Could it be a transparency issue?

Comment: I have been able to use color-theme http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/ to get better colors, but I guess it is not straight forward to get the colors equal everywhere.  Don't know the factors that are involved.